# Ringing volume is reduced after after updating Moto G2 to Android Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, calls, motorola-moto-g2, volume

After updating my Moto G2 to Lollipop 5.0, the ringing volume of my phone is reduced. Can anyone help me with a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to perform clear cache on your device. This steps will remove any temporary files that may be causing the problem, but will not delete your files or settings.

1. With the phone powered off, press and hold the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> button at the same time and release after two sec.
2. Press the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> button twice to highlight "Recovery mode"
3. Press the <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> button to restart into Recovery mode.
   You'll see an image of an Android robot with a red exclamation mark and the words "No command."
4. Hold the <kbd>Power</kbd> button, do not release it, press the <kbd>Volume up</kbd> button and release it (hold on the <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> button and release).
5. Use the volume buttons to scroll to "Wipe cache partition" and press the <kbd>Power</kbd> button to select it.
6. "Reboot system now" will be highlighted, press the <kbd>Power</kbd> button to select it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help as my Moto g 2nd Gen had the same problem and it's running ok for now.

You are going to need to plug your phone into a computer and on AUTO PLAY click "OPEN FOLDER TO VIEW FILES".

1. Go to Media folder > Audio > Ringtones
2. Copy all ringtones and go back 3 tabs to the main storage page of your phone
3. Open Ringtones folder and paste your ringtones
4. Close the window, unplug your phone and cross your fingers it has solved your problem.

Worked for me so I hope this helps others.